# Docker: Dockerfile vs docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a `Dockerfile` as the following:

```
FROM docker/whalesay:latest
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y fortunes
CMD while true; do /usr/games/fortune -a | cowsay; sleep 2; done
```

I have built the above `Dockerfile` as image: `docker-whale`

I want to write a `docker-compose.yml` for the above image. My understanding is that you can run multiple containers with docker-compose.

So if i want to run 5 images of `docker-whale`, how does `docker-compose.yml` looks like?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could put this `docker-compose.yaml` next to your `Dockerfile`:

```
version: '2'
services:
  docker-whale:
    image: docker-whale
    build: .
```

And then execute the following commands:

```
# build docker image
docker-compose build

# bring up one docker container
docker-compose up -d

# scale up to three containers
docker-compose scale docker-whale=3

# overview about these containers
docker-compose ps

# view combined logs of all containers
# use <ctrl-c> to stop viewing
docker-compose logs --follow

# take down all containers
docker-compose down
```

Answer (score 5):

```
version:"3" 
services: docker-whale: 
   image:docker-whale 
   deploy: 
     replicas:5
     resources:
      limits: 
        cpus:"0.1"
        memory: 50M
     restart_policy: 
        condition: on-failure
  ports: "80:80"
```

...

Above is how your docker-compose.yml should look like. This docker-compose.yml tells Dockers to do the following:

1. pull the image docker-wale that you build in previous step.
2. Run five instances of that image as a service called docker-whale, limiting each one to use, at most,10% of the CPU (across all cores), and 50MB of RAM.
3. Immediately restart containers if one fails
4. Map port 80 on the host to docker-whale's port 80...

Ref:https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part3/#docker-composeyml

Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want to run 5 containers of docker-whale and not 5 images .

In your case compose.yml will not have information about number of containers. You need to use scale command

```
docker-compose scale <service-name>=5
```

Answer (score -1):

**docker-compose.yml**

```
docker-whale:
  image: docker-whale
```

**Then inside same folder run:**

```
docker-compose up -d
docker-compose scale docker-whale=5
```

This assumes your application is scale-aware, but you still can write 5 entries in docker-compose.yml, this is screwdriver but sometimes useful:

```
docker-whale-1:
  image: docker-whale

docker-whale-2:
  image: docker-whale

docker-whale-3:
  image: docker-whale

docker-whale-4:
  image: docker-whale

docker-whale-5:
  image: docker-whale
```

Comment: @atv can you please explain what exactly is wrong with this?

Comment: See the accepted answer. scale command should be used to spawn number of instances